Winforms C# - parse DataTable into existing BufDataGridView binding source
I'm trying to write code that parses through the rows of a CSV and imports them into an existing bufDataGridView binding source named "Test" with columns already named in the binding source.  The bufDataGridView is named "TestData" and the columns are SerialNo, Data1, Data2, etc.
I can parse the csv and load all of the data into a data table with the code:
FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
OpenFileDialog loadDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

loadDialog.Filter = "comma separated values source file|*.csv";
loadDialog.Title = "Load Data";
if (loadDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    return;

string csvSelectedFile = loadDialog.FileName;

readCSV(csvSelectedFile);

DataTable readCSV(string filePath)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    // Creating the columns
    File.ReadLines(filePath).Take(1)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => dt.Columns.Add(x.Trim()));

    // Adding the rows
    File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(1)
        .Select(x => x.Split(','))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(line => dt.Rows.Add(line));
    return dt;
}

So now dt has all of the data within it, so now how do i transplant that data into TestData?
I might have gone about this all wrong, so please let me know how you would do it :)

not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve but you can set the datatable as datasource of you grid:
dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

or set it as datasource of a bindingsource:
bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

you can have a look at this

In addition to this helpful comment,TestData object need to have properties which has  exactly same name and type of the columns you supply within dt to trigger autobinding.
